# Dent detection after hail

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

The following picture is a photo of hail damage on a car, taken with fringe projection.

[image]

I want to detect the dents and classify them (big ones in yellow and small ones in red).

[image]

How can I do that? Which algorithm / method do you suggest?

Comment: Which programming language? Have you tried anything yet? I guess computing the magnitude of the gradient would be a good start. Or computing the standard deviation with neighborhood pixels

Comment: For the langage, Python will be fine but C++ is good too, I use OpenCV for the image processing.

Comment: I try to compute the skeletonization of the image to be able to  find 'curved' lines. Another thing I can test is using Fourier transform filtering to try to remove the parallel lines. I don't know if it's a good idea. I'm searching for ideas / methods / algorithms.

Comment: @PhilippeJuhel : Can you please tell me which algorithm / language you used for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinning isn't a bad idea, but actually you don't really need it if you can binarize: the blob outlines will give equally good curves.

[image]

[image]

Follow every curve in turn and estimate the curvature, for instance by determining the deviation from a line segment between two points fifty pixels apart.

The sections of the curve with a significant deviation will tell you where damage is found.